# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp8.net4india.com, port: 25;

Tags: java, email, smtp

While sent email showing error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp8.net4india.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

My email settings is:

```
        String mailProcessed = "";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp8.net4india.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(frmMail, frmPass);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`

and add `props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");`

You are using SSL, not TLS.

Also make sure the mail server supports SSL.

Also make sure that the mail server is using TCP protocol `SMTP`, they might be using `IMAP` or `POP3`.
In that case you need to change the properties you reference by the protocol they use, i.e:
`props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "25");`
`props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");`

You are using `getDefaultInstance` for the session, but if a session was already established it will return the existing session and your properties will be lost.

Check the common mistakes page, it has it all:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes

Comment: try to add property : `mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true`